# How to respond to someone who says "Pleasure to meet you", but you don't feel the exact same thing?

Tags: expressions, politeness

It is not that I hated meeting him, but it wasn't a "pleasure" either. Not because I have some problems with him but because I don't get usually enchanted when meeting someone for the first time.

I don't want to lie by saying "Same here"!

How to respond to someone who says "Pleasure to meet you", but you don't feel the exact same thing?

Comment: This is not about English Language. It's about etiquette. Every day we have to say things we don't always mean. If somenone says "Good morning", you are expected to greet the same way. This is called "good manners", "a social convention", whatever. When a stranger asks you "How are you doing", you are not expected to stop and tell him all the misfortunes you've had. The same way, you may not be glad meeting a certain person, but you just have to say something that is socially acceptable, unless you want people to hate you.

Comment: Maybe just *Hello*?

Comment: Say "It's a pleasure to be met."

Comment: "I am sure" is sufficiently ambiguous etiquette-wise. Likely be misunderstood as "Charmed, I'm sure". Technically, neither says anything about *your* feelings.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - This is *not* sufficiently ambiguous etiquette-wise, even though it is true that any reasonably polite person will interpret it as charitably as possible.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - Have to send the usage in to "Miss Manners" to be sure, but you're quite possibly correct. What's acceptable varies a lot depending on situation, and "I am sure" might get you branded a heathen in some circles.

Comment: *The pleasure is mine.*

Answer (score 3):

This is a "stock phrase" used in a social situation.  It is neither expected nor required that it be literally true.  Typically, the only reason to depart from it is if you deliberately wanted to be rude.

If it makes you feel better, tell yourself that it doesn't mean what it appears to, by convention (as with any other idiom).  Viewed in this light, it's no more a lie than "it's raining cats and dogs."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go all Agatha Christie or Dorothy Sayers on him, you respond, "Likewise, I'm sure." After all, he may be lying about it being a pleasure on HIS part.

Or, if you're not willing to take chances, just smile and say "Hi!", then ask a question like "What company are you with?" or whatever is appropriate.